# Spring 5 Rest Service Invocation Issue

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm having an issue with consuming a REST service in Spring 5. The scenario: user updates a field or two on a screen and clicks a button. That calls a Spring controller which in turn makes two REST calls in series to gather information that is then returned to the browser. Our current production version uses Spring 4 and works great. But after upgrading to 5, the service invocations fail unless I put the server into debug mode and debug through the part of the code that does the two calls. If I debug, it works as expected. If I don't debug, I get a NullPointerException because the code uses information retrieved by the REST call that isn't there because it closed the connection before the REST service could return the information. Maybe there's a new dependency I missed or something I've overlooked when I upgraded to Spring 5 from 4, or something, but I've never seen anything like this.

Edit: Here's the code responsible for the REST service call:

```
ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>(){});
```

restTemplate is an autowired instance of org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate. Whether the call completes or not, I always get a ResponseEntity. But when the call terminates early, the body data is null, which is incorrect. There will always be body data returned by call, and Spring 4 always captures it correctly. Spring 5 only captures it correctly when I debug through the code, but fails during normal execution - I see this when I examine captured data.

Comment: can you share how you do the calls? , how the service invocations fail? please share the exceptions

Comment: If you want help from SO, always throw in some code, what you've tried already etc.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a solution - the problem likely resides in the JDK version I have. I switched the request factory to HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, and voila, no more problem.